# Carrierwave + Mongoid + gridfs + Padrino admin image upload

Tags: ruby, mongoid, carrierwave, gridfs, padrino

i'm trying to get carrierwave + mongoid + gridfs to work for uploading images via padrino admin and then showing on front-end. at a loss as to glue everything. can someone help?

following https://blog.engineyard.com/2011/a-gentle-introduction-to-carrierwave/ and https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave-mongoid.

trying to persist an "Artwork" with an image upload returns:

> NoMethodError at /admin/artworks/update/53a0eedcf2c7961066000002
>   undefined method `**bson_dump**' for # file:
>   hash.rb location: block in **bson_dump** line: 15

```
mongofiles -d database list
```

returning empty.

question is: what's wrong with the code at the moment?

uploader: https://github.com/bcsantos/debug/blob/master/lib/uploader.rb

```
class Uploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  ##
  # Image manipulator library:
  #
  include CarrierWave::RMagick
  # include CarrierWave::ImageScience
  # include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  ##
  # Storage type
  #
  storage :grid_fs
  # configure do |config|
  #   config.fog_credentials = {
  #     :provider              => 'XXX',
  #     :aws_access_key_id     => 'YOUR_ACCESS_KEY',
  #     :aws_secret_access_key => 'YOUR_SECRET_KEY'
  #   }
  #   config.fog_directory = 'YOUR_BUCKET'
  # end
  # storage :fog

resize_to_limit(1024, 768)

  ## Manually set root
  def root; File.join(Padrino.root,"public/"); end

  ##
  # Directory where uploaded files will be stored (default is /public/uploads)
  #
  def store_dir
    'content'
  end

  ##
  # Directory where uploaded temp files will be stored (default is [root]/tmp)
  #
  def cache_dir
    Padrino.root("tmp")
  end

  ##
  # Default URL as a default if there hasn't been a file uploaded
  #
  # def default_url
  #   "/images/fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_')
  # end

  ##
  # Process files as they are uploaded.
  #
  # process :resize_to_fit => [740, 580]

  ##
  # Create different versions of your uploaded files
  #
  # version :header do
  #   process :resize_to_fill => [940, 250]
  #   version :thumb do
  #     process :resize_to_fill => [230, 85]
  #   end
  # end
  ##
  # White list of extensions which are allowed to be uploaded:
  #
  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end

  ##
  # Override the filename of the uploaded files
  #
  # def filename
  #   "something.jpg" if original_filename
  # end
end
```

## -----------

upload https://github.com/bcsantos/debug/blob/master/app/models/upload.rb

```
class Upload
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps # adds created_at and updated_at fields

  # field <name>, :type => <type>, :default => <value>
  field :file, :type => String
  field :created_at, :type => Time

  attr_accessible :upload

  mount_uploader :upload, Uploader


  # You can define indexes on documents using the index macro:
  # index :field <, :unique => true>

  # You can create a composite key in mongoid to replace the default id using the key macro:
  # key :field <, :another_field, :one_more ....>
end
```

## -----------

model i want to associate the upload/picture with https://github.com/bcsantos/debug/blob/master/app/models/artwork.rb

```
class Artwork
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps # adds created_at and updated_at fields

  # field <name>, :type => <type>, :default => <value>
  field :name, :type => String
  field :year, :type => Integer
  field :author, :type => String
  field :rent_price, :type => String
  field :sale_price, :type => String
  field :medium, :type => String
  field :size, :type => String
  field :colour, :type => String

  field :picture, :type => Upload
  field :thumbnail, :type => Upload


  # You can define indexes on documents using the index macro:
  # index :field <, :unique => true>

  # You can create a composite key in mongoid to replace the default id using the key macro:
  # key :field <, :another_field, :one_more ....>
end
```

## -----------

controller to retrieve files from database (thanks @Darío)

```
TourApart::App.controllers do

  get :gridfs, map: '/content/*' do
    gridfs_file = Mongoid::GridFS[params[:splat]]
    content_type gridfs_file.content_type
    gridfs_file.data
  end

  error Mongoid::Errors::MongoidError do
    halt 404, 'File not found'
  end

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, given this model design, your Artwork model isn't properly embedding the `Upload` document. It should instead embed the `picture` and `thumbnail` field like so:

```
class Artwork
  # ...
  embeds_one :picture, class_name: "Upload"
  embeds_one :thumbnail, class_name: "Upload"
  # ...
end
```

Aside, I don't understand why you have an `Upload` document in the first place. It seems unnecessary given your design. The `Uploader` holds all the information that you're trying to store in your `Upload` model. For example, your `Artwork` model could instead just look like this (and you can dump the `Upload` model all together):

```
class Artwork
  # ...
  mount_uploader :picture, Uploader
  mount_uploader :thumbnail, Uploader
  # ...
end
```

Your `picture` and `thumbnail` field will hold things like the date it was updated, the filename, the file date, etc.

Also, it looks like you're trying to manually manage the `thumbnail`. I presume the thumbnail is a smaller version of the `picture`. Carrierwave can handle this for you too:

```
class Artwork
  # ...
  mount_uploader :picture, Uploader
  # ...
end
```

Then add something like this to your `Uploader`:

```
class Uploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  # ...
  version :thumbnail do
    process resize_to_fill: [160, 120]
  end
  # ...
end
```

That way, you'll have a `Artwork#picture` and a `Artwork#picture_thumbnail` accessor for the two different versions.

More examples:

- `Artwork#picture.read` - get the image data
- `Artwork#picture.file` - get the image file
- `Artwork#picture_thumbnail.file` - get the thumbnail version's file
- `Artwork#picture.file.content_type` - yup, the content_type
- etc

Lastly, if you're using carrierwave-mongoid, there's no need to access `Mongoid::GridFS` directly in your controller. Look-up the artwork and just access the `picture` field. Let GridFS stay behind the scenes.

Aside, I would recommend using `CarrierWave::MiniMagick` over `CarrierWave::RMagick`. It just makes things easier in the long run, IMO, but it requires that you have ImageMagick installed on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

This took a while... to help others save time, here goes:

**gemfile**

```
#...
gem 'mongoid', '~>3.0.0'
gem 'carrierwave-mongoid', :require => 'carrierwave/mongoid'
gem 'mini_magick', :require => 'mini_magick'
#...
```

**lib/uploader.rb**

```
class Uploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  storage :grid_fs

  ##
  # Directory where uploaded files will be stored (default is /public/uploads)
  #
  def store_dir
    '/content/images'
  end

  ##
  # Directory where uploaded temp files will be stored (default is [root]/tmp)
  #
  def cache_dir
    Padrino.root("/tmp")
  end

  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end

  ##
  # Override the filename of the uploaded files
  #
  # def filename
  #   "something.jpg" if original_filename
  # end
end
```

**model**

```
class Thing
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :name, :type => String
  field :year, :type => Integer
  #...

  mount_uploader :picture, Uploader
end
```

**controller**

```
YourApp::App.controllers :things do

  get :image, with: [:id], provides: ['.jpeg', '.jpg', '.png', '.gif'] do
    thing = Thing.find(params[:id])
    content_type thing.picture.content_type
    response.write(thing.picture.read)

  end

  error Mongoid::Errors::MongoidError do
    halt 404, 'File not found'
  end

end
```

**view (haml)**

```
/...
%img{:src => url_for(:things, :image, thing.id)}/
/...
```

**admin/views/things/_form.haml**

```
/...
%fieldset.control-group{:class => error ? 'has-error' : ''}
  =f.label :picture, :class => 'control-label'
  .controls
    =f.file_field :picture, :class => 'form-control input-large input-with-feedback'
    %span.help-inline=error ? f.error_message_on(:picture, :class => 'file-error') : pat(:example)
/...
```

Thanks @Ryan McGeary and @Darío.